# Get data from URL with value

Tags: html, laravel

I have URL like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hasil-transaksi?data%5B0%5D%5B%5D=0000260&data%5B0%5D%5Bno_transaksi%5D=KRJ22010001
```

How to get **KRJ22010001** from that URL?

Comment: Is that a string or an actual page/url on your server?

Comment: edit to add: it is an actual url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
[urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php) to decode your string,
[parse_​url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the query and [parse_​str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get its components:

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/hasil-transaksi?data%5B0%5D%5B%5D=0000260&data%5B0%5D%5Bno_transaksi%5D=KRJ22010001';
$url_decoded = urldecode($url);
$query = parse_url($url_decoded, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $parsed_query);

echo $parsed_query['data'][0]['no_transaksi'];
```

will output KRJ22010001

Comment: it works, but what if i want to do it not just with URL KRJ22010001? I mean make it automatic?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic"? `$parsed_query` is an array of all query parameters (`var_dump($parsed_query)`)

Comment: I mean to define the $url. when its KRJXXXX02 that means i have to change the code above again manually?

Comment: No, no need to change the code.

Comment: I got it with $currentURL = url()->full();
thank you so much!

Comment: So ... it _is_ an actual URL and not a string as you mentioned?

Comment: i'm sorry for mistaken it... yes it is an actual url

Comment: Ok, no problem. Was this answer actually useful, did you use any of the code I posted? If not, I'll remove this answer, since it is irrelevant then - and you might want to remove your comment stating it is a string, might confuse others. ;)

Comment: don't remove this answer, this is really helpful. I used it with added url()->full(); for $url. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: can i ask you again @brombeer? this is an actual url, and when i used your code it will get bug/error in the future or not?

Comment: I don't think there will be any problems with an actual URL - but there probably are more elegant solutions to get query parameters from the actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

TO get querystring you can use the Request Object. Following example for your controller:

```php
public function exampleShow(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    dd( $request->input('no_transaksi') );
}
```

Comment: no error, but i got null result, what goes wrong? my input?

Comment: @DearJanice Maybe you dont have any data where the query not match? Check your querystring.

Comment: with dd($request) i got no_transaksi = null, i got KRJ22010001 value for no_transaksi after submit. And i have to execute no_transaksi value